# twitter bootstrap not working in ie8 on the top site (i.e. www.exampleurl.com)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, url, internet-explorer-8, html5shiv, respond.js

I created a responsive website with twitter bootstrap 3. I found out that it isn't working in ie8 so I added the recommended files html5shiv.min.js and respond.min.js to my index.html.
All is working fine when I explicitly go to www.exampleurl.com/index.html. As soon as I only go to www.exampleurl.com (which also shows the content of the index.html, as you know) it isn't working anymore.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
website-folder-name
--bootstrap
----bootstrap.css
--css
----common.css
--de
----<all german sites>
--en
----<all english sites>
--img
----<all images>
--js
----common.js
----html5shiv.min.js
----jquery-1.11.3.min.js
----respond.min.js
--index.html
```

My html code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15" />   
  <!--IE Fix-->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>
    My Website
  </title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />    

  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/common.js"></script>

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <!-- bootstrap html code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody has an idea how to consider the bootstrap fixes also on my exampleurl.com, not only on the subsites. I don't want to redirect from exampleurl.com to exampleurl.com/index.html with the htaccess file. When someone visits my site I want him to be on exampleurl.com, not a 'subsite'.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache? I think it works on index.html  because it considers it to be a different URL that is not it the cache. So you have to clear the cache for that domain and try loading it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was the solution! Really easy actually =)